# Can browser.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}) ever return more than one tab?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

My extension needs to do something with the currently active tab. So I use

```
browser.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}).then((tabs) =>
  let tab = tabs[0];
  if (tab) {
    // actual code
  } else {
    log("no active tab")
  }
);
```

Mostly out of curiosity: are there cases where `tabs` will have more than one tab?

Comment: That would be a bug in the browser which you can report on https://crbug.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR: No**

For Chrome, Opera and Firefox this is currently impossible, so it's safe to assume that the array will only contain one element.

Opera has multi-select of tabs, but it uses the property `highlighted` to indicate the multi-select status. `active` means "visibly selected in window": the contents of the tab are visible in the browser window.

browser.tabs.query returns an array, regardless of the filter you pass to it. It also returns an array when filtering on "index", containing one result if you have one window open.

Comment: "Multi-select of tabs" is available in Chrome and the term in chrome.tabs API is `highlight`. It's not the same as `active`. On the oher hand, Vivaldi has tab stacking and tab splitting, but it's implemented as extData property.